# How to deal with the android BUILD_PREBUILT?

Tags: android, android-source

if I have a third part apk signed with their key. 
I made it prebuilt with our device, in ics, this should be done with BUILD_PREBUILT, the apk must be signed with our key, but when the user get the device how could they upgrade the apk
with the newest version the third part provided? (the certificates is not same).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the option of **not** resigning the apk when using BUILD_PREBUILT by setting the `LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := PRESIGNED`

Here is a full example of a makefile for this kind of use:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := MyApp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_MODULE).apk
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
# tell dexopt not to try resigning the apks
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := PRESIGNED

include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

Comment: how to PREBUILT .so likewise?